# How to create multiple cells and set each character into each cell using iText 5 in Java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am a newbie to `iText`.

I have a task of populating data into pdf file. I have succeeded in populating remaining data into the pdf file but the idNumber.

Id number is of 13 characters where each character of id number should set into each cell.

**Example:**

**IDNumber:** `1224729101234`

**Step 1.** In my java code I get the IDNumber value as a string.

**Step 2.** I am splitting this string into characters using java's `toCharArray()` to set each character into each cell (Like each character set into each small box).

```
IDNumber(should look like this in each cell with cell borders) : 1   2   2   4   7   2   9   1   0   1   2   3   4
```

**I am using Java 8 and iText 5.x.**

Can any one please help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you prvide a code sample of what you have tried so far, and what error you are getting specifically, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this.

```
String[] charArray = originalString.split("");
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(charArray.length);
table.setSpacingAfter(5f);
for (final String char : charArray) {
    PdfPCell cell =  new PdfPCell(new Phrase(char, formCellValueFont));
    cell.setBorderWidth(1f);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(cell);
}
```